# How to select duplicate records without a primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

If I run this query:

```
SELECT 
        a,
        b,
        c,
        ...
FROM    [DMS].[dbo].[CreditDebitAdjustment]
```

I get 24197 records.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        a,
        b,
        c,
        ...
FROM    [DMS].[dbo].[CreditDebitAdjustment]
```

I get 24176 records.

How do I go about selecting only the rows that are identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
        a,
        b,
        c
FROM    [DMS].[dbo].[CreditDebitAdjustment]
group by a,b,c
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete those duplicates, use

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
      a, b, c,
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c ORDER BY ...(define how to order those rows)..)
   FROM    
      [DMS].[dbo].[CreditDebitAdjustment]
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

This "partitions" (groups) all your data by the tuple `(a,b,c)` and gives each row a number - starting at 1 for each new tuple.

So any cases where you have a `RowNum` that's larger than 1 - that's a duplicate, and I delete it away.

But really: any serious data table **ought to have** a proper primary key!